# Display selected options from checkbox to a new list in next tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

I want to display the selected options from my checkbox list in a new list in a new `Tkinter` window and when browsing it comes back to the main screen
(using Python 3.5 with Ubuntu 16.04).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

lista=['jpeg','jfit','tiff','gif','png','bmp']    
class PopUp(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, number=10):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.global_state = tk.BooleanVar()

        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="select/deselect all", variable=self.global_state, command=self.select_clear_states)
        cb.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=1)

        self.states = []

        for n in range(len(lista)):
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=str(lista[n]), variable=var)
            cb.grid(row=n+1, column=0, padx=5, pady=1)
            self.states.append(var)

    def select_clear_states(self):
        state = self.global_state.get()
        for x in self.states:
            x.set(state)

def popup(num):
    win = PopUp(num)

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="5 checkboxes", command=lambda:popup(5))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. You told us what you want, but haven't explained what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, if you wanted to do this with `Checkbutton`s you could do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.top = Toplevel(root)
        self.frame = Frame(self.top)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.check = []
        self.var = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.var.append(IntVar())
            self.var[i].trace("w", self.callback)
            self.check.append(Checkbutton(self.root, text="Option "+str(i), variable=self.var[i]))
            self.check[i].pack()
    def callback(self, *args):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self.top)
        self.frame.pack()
        for i, c in zip(self.check, self.var):
            if c.get() == 1:
                Label(self.frame, text=i.cget("text")).pack()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively you might find that a `Listbox` accomplishes what you want and (IMO) looks a lot cleaner and more user friendly:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
        self.listbox.pack()
        for i in range(10):
            self.listbox.insert(END, "Option "+str(i))

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Using the `Listbox` you probably wouldn't even need two windows as the selection quite clearly shows which options are selected by highlighting them.